# Update/Refresh Magento UI grid column data only with Javascript (No Ajax)

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, order-grid

We have created Mass Action status updates in the grid.

1. Updating the status using the mass action, an ajax call will be initiated and updated the data in the server.
2. Another ajax call will refresh the UI grid.

Any help on get rid of the second ajax call would be appreciated, since the grid is already using a KO template, I am wondering why don't we just update the column data to get that reflect on the grid to save the second ajax page load time.